# How to put onload events on SharePoint 2013 scriptlinks?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

In my page layout, I want to load a javascript file and put a onload event on it like

```
<script onload="console.log(this)" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

But however in SharePoint page layouts, I am using this style

```
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/Style Library/en-US/myfile.js" runat="server" OnDemand="False" LoadAfterUI="True"/>-->
```

How can I attach an onload event where I can pass `this` like in the first example?